# How to configure and send mail with Postfix using a PHPmailer?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, postfix-mta

I have a PHPmailer class, downloaded from an example. I configured and installed Postfix and mailutils, but I don't know the parameters to configure the phpmailer with postfix. I tried as it is and I get the error: `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

```
  public $From          = 'me@example.com';
  public $FromName      = 'Me';
  public $Host          = 'localhost';
  public $Port          = 25;
  public $Helo          = '';
  public $SMTPSecure    = ''; // empty, ssl or tls
  public $SMTPAuth      = false;
  public $Username      = '';
  public $Password      = '';
```

How I have to configure `/etc/postfix/main.cf` config file and what I have to insert in the PHPmailer fields?

Comment: So you are going to need to hit the manual again

Comment: your question is too vague... you may want to post your postfix config file, and even before that, run wireshark or tcpdump on port 25 on localhost, and see how your phpmailer communicates with postfix. Normally, default postfix confuration does not require any authentication on localhost.

Comment: I cannot understand what the the phpmailer means, if username and password are related to those of the system or not, I do not know what. Please help me because I know very little. @spamsink

Comment: Ok. Maybe just write about what is it you are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

PHPmailer will send mail by invoking the php `mail()` function and using postfix as the user that is making the request.  For example, on an Ubuntu based system that will be www-data if called by apache using PHP. In short, no authentication is required as long as `SMTPAuth = true;` is **NOT** set. `SMTPAuth` is only required if you are connecting to a remote mail server to authenticate and deliver the mail.

To solve your problem.  **Remove the lines that relate to** `SMTPAuth` to use the locally install postfix server.

You can reference https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples for various examples using PHPmailer.